# Using UPDATE statement in sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I know it's easier to use base R to update value, but I have to do it in sqldf.
I have a data frame, and I want to update a field based on conditions. If column2 is 'c', then update the value in column1.

```
column1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
column2 <- c("a","b","c","d")
temp <- data.frame(column1,column2)
sqldf("
      UPDATE temp
      set column1=100
      WHERE column2 ='c'
      ")
```

above code give me "data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows" and warning message "In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) : SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery()." The result is the table is never updated/changed.

Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: See the `sqldf` [README](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update) (you might need to manually scroll down to FAQ #8). Long-story-short: `sqldf` never updates the environment, you have to update internally then `select` all of the data and capture the "new" data. Example: `sqldf(c("update DF set b = a where b is null", "select * from main.DF"))`.

Comment: I want to save the "new" data into a dataframe by doing this "sqldf(c("update DF set b = a where b is null", "create table new as select * from main.DF"))" But I got "data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows". Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think that's the best way to use `sqldf`. The package author/maintainer frequents SO, perhaps he can shed light on this (and perhaps improve my answer). @G.Grothendieck?

Comment: (backpedal ... I used *"he"* but it very easily could be *"she"* or some other pronoun ... it doesn't matter to me other than I would much prefer to use what they prefer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is both known and intentional: `sqldf` never tries to update objects in the environment. It merely acts as a conduit by copying data into a sqlite (temp) database and running the query, never does the package intend to overwrite the source objects in the calling environment.

Reference FAQ 8 in the [`sqldf` README](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update):

> Although data frames referenced in the SQL statement(s) passed to sqldf are automatically imported to SQLite, sqldf does not automatically export anything for safety reasons. Thus if you update a table using sqldf you must explicitly return it as shown in the examples below.

Using your data:

```r
sqldf(c("
       UPDATE temp
       set column1=100
       WHERE column2 ='c'
       ", "select * from main.temp"))
# Warning in result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
#   SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().
#   column1 column2
# 1       1       a
# 2       2       b
# 3     100       c
# 4       4       d
```

(You can safely ignore that warning, it's because the first statement returns nothing.)

So to actually use this to update the object in-place in your environment, you'd need to capture the output yourself.

```r
temp
#   column1 column2
# 1       1       a
# 2       2       b
# 3       3       c
# 4       4       d
temp <- suppressWarnings(sqldf(c("
      UPDATE temp
      set column1=100
      WHERE column2 ='c'
      ", "select * from main.temp")))
temp
#   column1 column2
# 1       1       a
# 2       2       b
# 3     100       c
# 4       4       d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works! One more follow-up question, What should I do if I want to set two fields? temp <- suppressWarnings(sqldf(c(" UPDATE temp set column1=100 WHERE column2 ='c'; set column1=200 WHERE column2 ='b' ", "select * from main.temp")))

Comment: That's a generic SQL question, and ... I don't think it works like that. You'll need multiple `update` statements. Try: `sqldf(c("UPDATE temp set column1=100 WHERE column2 ='c'", "UPDATE temp set column1=200 WHERE column2 ='b'", "select * from main.temp"))`.

Comment: There are alternatives using `upsert` methodology, link: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html. (Untested, not sure if `sqldf`'s architecture would support it.) (**Edit**: nope, not directly at least, sqlite's upsert requires unique keys, which are not known to anyone (but you) and I do not know if `sqldf` allows you to set them (no research done). `sqldf(c("insert into temp (column1,column2) values (100,'c'),(200,'b')", "select * from main.temp"))` fails.)

Comment: But frankly, if you're getting into the world of upsert ... you should just go "all in" and deal with a non-temporary database, whether sqlite or some other DBMS.

Comment: Okay, I spoke too soon ... `sqldf(c("create unique index idx1 on temp (column2)", "insert into temp (column1,column2) values (100,'c'),(200,'b') on conflict (column2) do update set column1=excluded.column1", "select * from main.temp"))` works by doing an upsert and returning the new frame. But frankly, is it worth this much effort? I have done no testing (with larger frames) to see the impact that creating a new unique index will have on things. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I switched to case when statement. Thanks so much again for your time! it's very helpful