# SQL delete query not executing using sqldf in R

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, sql-delete, sqldf

I have a table - "cla_retail" - in sql that has 20,000+ rows. I have read the tables in R using dbConnect and stored it in a dataframe called "cla_retail_df"
I am trying to execute a DELETE query using sqldf on dataframe abc. This delete query works fine when I execute it in mySQL but returns 0 results when I execute it in R.

I also tried using dplyr but I got confused with the many "not" in the sql query.
I have initialised the other dataframes

1. sales_vou_main_appr,
2. issue_to_karigar_approval_main ,
3. issue_to_hallmark_main ,
4. sample_issue_to_karigar_main

Here is what I have tried in R and throws 0 rows in abc_v2:

```
abc <- cla_retail_df

abc_v2<- sqldf("delete from abc where status<>'N' and barcode not in(select barcode from sales_vou_main_appr where ret_status='0') and barcode not in(select barcode from issue_to_karigar_approval_main where ret_status='0') and barcode not in(select barcode from issue_to_hallmark_main where rec_status='0') and barcode not in(select barcode from sample_issue_to_karigar_main where rec_status='0')")
```

Comment: This is mostly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61373594/3358272 (and therefore [sqldf FAQ 8](https://github.com/cran/sqldf#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update) is relevant), though you're using `DELETE` instead of `UPDATE`. The premise is (I believe) the same: `sqldf` doesn't delete in-place, and it never returns automatically. If you want `abc_vw` to be the contents of `cla_retail_df` without the rows, then `abc_v2 <- sqldf(c("delete from abc where ...", "select * from abc"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in dplyr:

```r
lapply(list(sales_vou_main_appr, issue_to_karigar_approval_main,
            issue_to_hallmark_main, sample_issue_to_karigar_main),
       function(Z) filter(Z, ret_status == "0") %>% select(barcode)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  anti_join(cla_retail_df, by = "barcode") %>%
  filter(status != "N")
```

As for using `DELETE` in `sqldf`, realize that `sqldf` doesn't return data (on updates/deletes) by default for safety reasons (see the `sqldf` [FAQ 8](https://github.com/cran/sqldf#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update), scroll to question 8), you have to explicitly request it with a second query. Try:

```r
abc_v2 <- sqldf(c("delete from abc where ...",
                  "select * from abc"))
```

Realize that `"delete from abc where ..."` doesn't delete anything from the `data.frame` object `abc`, it deletes it from the (temporary?) table named `abc` in the in-memory SQLite database it uses by default (assuming you are using the SQLite engine of `sqldf`).